# Identify faulty PC part when no logs/dumps are produced

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, freeze, gpu

My best friend's PC completely freezes under any GPU extensive load. **No blue screens shown, no logs/dumps are produced**. Only reset helps.

Running on the integrated GPU, the freezes don't happen. I guess that should absolutely point to a faulty GPU, but you could also argue that an integrated GPU consumes less power (so it still could be a PSU problem) and doesn't use the same motherboard circuits as the dedicated one (so we can't write off the motherboard problems).

The GPU (GTX1060 3Gb) was bought several months ago from a dude on craigslist, who almost certainly turned out to be a miner. And here's a caveat: the GPU is still under warranty, but the guys from the service tested it and said **the GPU had no defects**. I feel like I shouldn't trust them completely in that regard since they're not motivated to find any issues :)

All temperatures are normal, the MB is ASRock Z77 Extreme4, the PSU (550W) was bought just recently and shouldn't really be the problem.

Is there any way which can help me to decisively find out which component is faulty? Note that there are no spare parts at hand.

Comment: Can I suggest a very simple first step? Disassemble the PC, clean things, and reassemble it. It could be something as simple as something being misstated or misconnected. Past that the PSU might be the problem if it’s not behaving correctly.

Comment: @JakeGould but how can badly assembled PC work at all? It used to work completely fine for a month or so, and even now it can run games/benchmarks for a few minutes before freezing. Wouldn't it be impossible if something wasn't properly inserted?

Comment: "but the guys from the service tested it and said the GPU had no defects." Demonstrate it to them, if you can reproduce the load reliably.

Comment: “It used to work completely fine for a month or so…” Case vibrations, movements your friend has not told you about, faulty parts that worked for a certain amount of time and then failed… Honestly if you cannot handle a basic task like disassembly and reassembly you are really sabotaging your own efforts to repair things.

Comment: @Enirsa _(My bad, I misread the Nvidia [specs](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/10-series/) page; in that case, please disregard my comments =] which I've deleted to prevent clutter)_. Re-seating the GPU and any other 12V rail components should be done to rule that out since it's an easy step that only takes a few minutes to do, and I would verify all components on the 12V rail are below the maximum amperage rating for that rail _(~45A appears to be the average for 550W PSUs)_. Testing with a known good PSU will rule out if the PSU itself is failing.